# http request not processing while emulating or running on real device mode but works fine with emulator

Tags: dart, flutter, localhost, httprequest

In my flutter application, i have user registration form which sends the data to an server using http request.

Whenever I submit the form and sending the request using the **emulator** (API 27 and android version 8.1) which works fine but in **real android device** it gives a error on **localhost** server

`SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111, address = 127.0.0.1, port = 48134`

I am working with Android device with version 7.1

**Code:**

```
final JsonDecoder _decoder = new JsonDecoder();

  Future<dynamic> post() {
    return http.post(
      "http://192.168.31.16:9091/myprj/api/register",
      body: json.encode({
        "username": "rahul",
        "password": "rahul",
        "email": "myemail@gmail.com",
      }),
      headers: {"Accept": "application/json","Content-type": "application/json",},
    ).then((http.Response response) {
      final String res = response.body;
      final int statusCode = response.statusCode;

      if (statusCode < 200 || statusCode > 400 || json == null) {
        throw new Exception("Error while fetching data");
      }
      return _decoder.convert(res);
    });
  }
```

Where, i have used local network IP `192.168.31.16` instead of `localhost`.
When i use live server address it works fine using android device also. The problem is only with localhost http request server with real android device.

Hope you understand my problem.

Comment: You need to add internet permissions in Android. By default it's only in debug builds.

Comment: Sorry, seems that's only planned, but not yet implemented https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20789

Comment: So you need to connect to localhost when you are running on your device?

Comment: @SamiKanafani unable to call REST API which is running on localhost using android device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with my firewall. Which blocking my port 9090.

So added the rule for firewall for port and now it works fine. BTW thanks to @rmtmckenzie

Comment: how to handle this error in flutter project of blocking port. using local ip for api.

Comment: Thanks alot. My spring application was listening on 0.0.0.0. My emulator connected successfully, Samsung S8 didnt. Adding Firewall rule for TCP port fixed that.

Answer (score 3):

This is most likely to do with how you're running your server, as that seems to be right so long as you've put in the right IP address and your device is connected to the same network.

Something that tripped me up once is that if you run your server on 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1', it may not actually be doing what you think it is. Those should both host in a local redirect that only allows access from your own computer. It's likely that the emulator has something set up so it acts like it's connecting to localhost.

If you run the server on 192.168.31.16 instead that will likely be more successful, but then you might not be able to access it from the emulator. So try running on 0.0.0.0:9091 as that means 'all IP addresses on the local machine', if you aren't already.

I'd advise putting in a dummy endpoint (like /healthz) on your server that just returns an html or plain-text page saying "It works" or something like that. Then open your phone's web browser and go there. If it works, you know that your phone is able to communicate with the computer and then we can start looking into coding issues. If it doesn't work, you know it's to do with the server's configuration.

Comment: Dude thanks for the answer, but none above working. And I already mentioned I'm running server using IP and there is no issue with the code. It works fine with live server ip and domain. But in case of local it work with only emulator

Comment: did you try browsing to the server on your mobile device? just so we can completely eliminate the possibility that it's something to do with the network/server set up.

Comment: This could also be a firewall or anti-virus problem. It might be worth trying with them disabled temporarily to see if it works, then you could add exceptions to them if needed.

Comment: It could be an ip4/ip6 issue.
If you are using localhost then try the code below and see what you get back.

import "dart:io";


main() {

  InternetAddress.lookup("localhost").then((a) => a.forEach(print));